# How to centre an item over a point in a Canvas?

Tags: xaml, canvas, listbox, windows-runtime

I'm using a ListBox with its DataTemplate containing a Canvas. I then bind the Left/Top of the Grid containing that Canvas to move it to a certain point.

I want to then have the child Grid centred at the X,Y coordinates I've specified, where the size of the child Grid is variable based on its content.  I was planning on achieving this by using a TranslateTransform to move the Grid by half of its width.

I can't see how I can set that TranslateTransform however as ElementName binding doesn't work within a DataTemplate.  Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SomeCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Grid x:Name="Container" 
                        Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" 
                        Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
                        Background="#88000000">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Container, Converter={StaticResource NegativeHalfConverter}}"
                                        Y="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Container, Converter={StaticResource NegativeHalfConverter}}" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" FontSize="36" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the fault wasn't with the binding itself, but with a feature that means the ActualWidth/ActualHeight properties aren't bindable. Thanks Filip.

To fix this I created a derived Grid with a couple of new dependency properties that I update in the SizeChanged events to have the ActualWidth/Height.  I then use my DataTemplate as above, binding to these new DPs to translate and centre my Grid on a point.  Seems to work a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I think ElementName binding should work in the name scope of a DataTemplate, but I have seen people complaining about bindings not updating correctly when binding to ActualWidth/Height properties. Perhaps instead of doing the complicated setup you have you could just implement an attached behavior that takes a Point parameter and updates the Canvas.Left/Top properties whenever the parameter or size of the associated object (your grid) changes.

Comment: Wait, implementing an attached behaviour that updates the Canvas Left/Top properties while keeping the original x,y is the "non complicated setup"? Would've thought translating it by half its width/height is far simpler!

Comment: Well, in your solution you had to create a new control, new dependency properties and do the translation in XAML. It would be a comparable effort to develop a reusable behavior/attached property where you would simply set a property like CanvasEx.Center={Binding Center} on your container factoring out/hiding the complexity of the calculations and event handling to the behavior that you could later also use elsewhere. The complicated part is that there is no built-in Behavior class, but there are open source ones on CodePlex or you can do your own attached property-based one.

Answer (score 0):

To move an object by half of its size you can use 2 rotations or scales: first is over 0.25,0.25 relative point, second is over the enter point 0.5,0.5. If you use rotations then angels are 180 degrees and -180 degrees. If you use scales then scale factors are -1,-1 and -1,-1.
Do not forget about RenderTransformOrigin property. And to apply two transforms you can apply them to two nested elements.